# Web Api OData v3 - Cast or IsOf Function must have a type in its arguments

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a base entity (`Store`), with two other types that implement it (`Customer`, `Engineer`).

However when I try to filter for a certain type:

```
http://localhost:50050/odata/Store?$inlinecount=allpages&$top=20&$filter=isof(MyNamespace.Data.Core.Entities.Engineer)&$orderby=Name%20asc
```

I get this error:

```
{
  "odata.error":{
    "code":"","message":{
      "lang":"en-US","value":"The query specified in the URI is not valid. Cast or IsOf Function must have a type in its arguments."
    },"innererror":{
      "message":"Cast or IsOf Function must have a type in its arguments.","type":"Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException","stacktrace":"   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.FunctionCallBinder.ValidateIsOfOrCast(BindingState state, Boolean isCast, List`1& args)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.FunctionCallBinder.CreateUnboundFunctionNode(FunctionCallToken functionCallToken, List`1 args, BindingState state)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.FunctionCallBinder.BindAsBuiltInFunction(FunctionCallToken functionCallToken, BindingState state, List`1 argumentNodes)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.FunctionCallBinder.BindFunctionCall(FunctionCallToken functionCallToken, BindingState state)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.MetadataBinder.BindFunctionCall(FunctionCallToken functionCallToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.MetadataBinder.Bind(QueryToken token)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.BinaryOperatorBinder.GetOperandFromToken(BinaryOperatorKind operatorKind, QueryToken queryToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.BinaryOperatorBinder.BindBinaryOperator(BinaryOperatorToken binaryOperatorToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.MetadataBinder.BindBinaryOperator(BinaryOperatorToken binaryOperatorToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.MetadataBinder.Bind(QueryToken token)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.FilterBinder.BindFilter(QueryToken filter)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.ODataUriParser.ParseFilterImplementation(String filter, IEdmType elementType, IEdmEntitySet entitySet)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.FilterQueryOption.get_FilterClause()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Validators.FilterQueryValidator.Validate(FilterQueryOption filterQueryOption, ODataValidationSettings settings)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.FilterQueryOption.Validate(ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Validators.ODataQueryValidator.Validate(ODataQueryOptions options, ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.Validate(ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ValidateQuery(HttpRequestMessage request, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)\r\n   at Vantage.Web.Api.Filters.AuthorizeQueryAttribute.ValidateQuery(HttpRequestMessage request, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions) in c:\\Users\\TimM\\Source\\Workspaces\\Workspace\\Vantage Web Prototype - API\\Vantage.Web.Api\\Filters\\AuthorizeQueryAttribute.cs:line 29\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ExecuteQuery(Object response, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)"
    }
  }
}
```

Why would this be happening? I have used the exact type being returned with the entity.

```
"odata.type":"MyNamespace.Data.Core.Entities.Engineer"
```

I am using Web Api 5.2.2, OData 5.3.1. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the type with single quotes, like this:

```
http://localhost:50050/odata/Store?$inlinecount=allpages&$top=20&$filter=isof('MyNamespace.Data.Core.Entities.Engineer')&$orderby=Name%20asc
```

When you do that though, you will get the following exception:

```
System.NotImplementedException: Unknown function 'isof'.
   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Expressions.FilterBinder.BindSingleValueFunctionCallNode(SingleValueFunctionCallNode node)
   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Expressions.FilterBinder.Bind(QueryNode node)
   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Expressions.FilterBinder.Bind(FilterClause filterClause, Type filterType, IEdmModel model, IAssembliesResolver assembliesResolver, ODataQuerySettings querySettings)
   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.FilterQueryOption.ApplyTo(IQueryable query, ODataQuerySettings querySettings, IAssembliesResolver assembliesResolver)
   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.ApplyTo(IQueryable query, ODataQuerySettings querySettings)
   at System.Web.Http.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ExecuteQuery(Object response, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Http.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
```

'isof' is ***not supported*** in the current version of the OData WebApi integration. You can look at the source code [here](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#OData/src/System.Web.Http.OData/OData/Query/Expressions/FilterBinder.cs). You will notice that the stacktrace talks about a method called `BindSingleValueFunctionCallNode`. There is a switch in there with the following `default` case:

```
default:
throw new NotImplementedException(Error.Format(SRResources.ODataFunctionNotSupported, node.Name));
```

Notice how the code does not test for the presence of either the `isof` or the `cast` functions. In the `ClrCanonicalFunctionNames` class, only these OData functions are defined:

```
// function names
internal const string StartswithFunctionName = "startswith";
internal const string EndswithFunctionName = "endswith";
internal const string SubstringofFunctionName = "substringof";
internal const string SubstringFunctionName = "substring";
internal const string LengthFunctionName = "length";
internal const string IndexofFunctionName = "indexof";
internal const string TolowerFunctionName = "tolower";
internal const string ToupperFunctionName = "toupper";
internal const string TrimFunctionName = "trim";
internal const string ConcatFunctionName = "concat";
internal const string YearFunctionName = "year";
internal const string YearsFunctionName = "years";
internal const string MonthFunctionName = "month";
internal const string MonthsFunctionName = "months";
internal const string DayFunctionName = "day";
internal const string DaysFunctionName = "days";
internal const string HourFunctionName = "hour";
internal const string HoursFunctionName = "hours";
internal const string MinuteFunctionName = "minute";
internal const string MinutesFunctionName = "minutes";
internal const string SecondFunctionName = "second";
internal const string SecondsFunctionName = "seconds";
internal const string RoundFunctionName = "round";
internal const string FloorFunctionName = "floor";
internal const string CeilingFunctionName = "ceiling";
```

I'm currently trying to implement my own `OfType` filtering with a querystring parameter.

Comment: Thanks for this. Shame that Microsoft aren't implementing so many of their own OData spec. Can you keep me up to date?

Comment: @Tim It really is a shame. We made some design decisions assuming that `isof` would work, and now we have to add a bunch of boilerplate code to made it work manually. It works in WCF Data Service as expected, and we used it extensively... The basic cases are easy to implement by hand actually, so if you need any help with it just post a specific question about it and I'll gladly try my best to help you out. Whenever MS updates this to support these functions, I'll be one of the first to fix my code to use them. I'll try to remember to report back to you then.

Comment: Yeah so have I. Class inheritance really depends on being able to separate them in queries, and now I am left with queries that won't work in a standardised way.

Comment: I've gotten around it by calling the different controllers for each type. Another problem I've realised is there isn't a good way to view only `Stores`, without also getting the inherited types `Customers` and `Engineers`. Makes me thing they need more functions aswell - `isnotof`, and `isexactlyof`.

Comment: I have a solution to emilt the ``OfType`` call to the query in order to simulate the ``isof`` function. See github.com/schungx/WebApi-OData for the code.

Comment: @StephenChung That's quite interesting... thanks for the link. I've used WCF Data Services in another project and it is a shame it was discontinued. If you are going to deprecate something, at least provide an alternative that works IMHO. WebApi lacks a lot of stuff that was possible with WCF Data.